# Нужно ли использовать css хаки в 2017 году

Tags: css

Нужно ли использовать css хаки в 2017 году? Например для border-rarius, border-box, box-shadow и так далее.

P.S. Верстаю для личного сайта, поддержка IE9+, ну и все остальные современные браузеры.

Comment: В зависимости от того, какие браузеры вы собираетесь поддерживать? (А это зависит от заказчика.)

Comment: @VladD верстаю для личного сайта, поддержка IE9+, ну и все остальные современные браузеры....

Comment: Ага, это важное дополнение, имеет смысл внести его в вопрос.

Comment: нужно ли? - Нет!!!, Можно ли? - почему нет!